# Set a theme for a single content types edit page

Tags: theming

How do you set the theme for the edit page for just one content type on your site?  I am using bootstrap for non-admin pages and using the default seven for the admin pages. So basically I need to override the admin theme of seven with the bootstrap theme, but only for one content type.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using hook_menu_alter you can override even the theme a path uses.

```
function hook_menu_alter( &$items)
{
    $items['path']['theme callback'] = 'variable_get';
    $items['path']['theme arguments'] = array('theme_default');
}
```

like this you set the theme for that path to whatever the user theme is, even for admins.

Comment: How would you do thus for an edit if a node because the path would be /node/{nodeid}/edit.  You cant set a path.

Comment: 'node/%nid/edit'. When in doubt, you can look for the hook_menu of the module that declared the path you want work on.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Content Theme](https://drupal.org/project/content_theme) module to assign theme for content creating, editing, and viewing pages.

This module features are :

- Assign a theme to all content. (This overrides the system default
  theme)
- Assign a theme to a content type. (This overrides content wide themes
  and system default)
- Assign a theme to a content node. (This overrides content type
  themes, content wide themes, and system default)
- Allow to use different themes on content creating/editing pages than
  on viewing pages.
     Fine-grained permission control.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, nothing seems to be working for overriding the seven them on the edit page. I loaded the content theme and it still did not change. When I debug it is showing boostrap sub theme being loaded first but then the seven theme loads last which I assume is causing this issue. Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Comment: what seemed to work is setting the admin to default theme (bootstrap subtheme) and changing the theme for /admin/* to the seven theme.